# Copy files from Linux to Windows using script

Tags: linux, pscp

I want to copy files from remote Linux server to my machine via some script which I can run in my machine.
I am trying with pscp command but it is showing me network error.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> pscp -pw password root@ipaddress:/var/log/messages \C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
ssh_init: Network error: Cannot assign requested address

Can anyone suggest what could be a possible error? also if any other alternative available for the same?

Comment: Why  do not you use from winscp?

Comment: Are you mentioning the port correctly?

Comment: @FarhadSarvari I want it to work as a script which I can run in Powershell.

Comment: @ParthShah Yes, it is using Port 22.

Comment: Is remote root login allowed?  That's usually considered a security blunder.

Answer (score 0):

```
pscp -P 22 -pw <password> root@ipaddress:/var/log/messages
```